# Different update permissions of same resource in REST API

Tags: api, rest, permissions

Assume I have a simple "employee" resource in a REST API:

```
{
    "employee_id": "1234ABCD",
    "name": "John Doe",
    "title": "Developer",
    "salary": 50000
}
```

Both employee and manager have permission to read the entire resource. The manager has permission to update all of the resource's properties, but the employee only has permission to update the `name` property.

The API supports partial updates of the resource through PATCH or POST or whatever (not important to the question). If the employee attempts to update `salary` (which he does not have permission to do), what would the appropriate response be? I see a few options, and I'm not sure what the most reasonable approach is:

- Ignore any fields in his update that he does not have permission to modify and return a 200 response. *This doesn't seem quite right because the API is saying "OK, I did it" when in fact it didn't update everything it was told to update.*
- Respond with 403 Forbidden. *This doesn't seem quite right because the employee does have permission to modify the resource, just not the all of the fields he is attempting to modify.*
- Respond with 400 Bad Request. *This doesn't seem quite right because the request actually wasn't bad, just "bad" for this user.*
- Some other response I hadn't considered?

What is the best response in a situation like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `403 Forbidden` status code means the server understood the request and the authorization credentials are valid, but insufficient. That seems to be the case.

An update like that shouldn't be allowed to succeed partially anyway, so the best response is `403 Forbidden`, and an explanation of the reason, if that's not a security concern.

Answer (score 0):

1) Remember that employee is just "pressing a button" in *your* software. So you have to make the decission based on what suits the business logic of *your* (client) software. For example, you may return 403 + body with a list of errors for each field.

2) Your client software should not allow an employee to do things, that the employee is not supposed to do. Which means that an employee will never even get a chance to edit the salary, if he/she does not posess the authority do so.

So the 403 is the most logical decission, because in essence it is a software error, not user's.